# Is there a word to describe the relationship between words like 'unicycle' and 'bicycle'?

Tags: grammatical-number

Pretty much what the title says. Some other examples would be twosome and threesome, triangle, rectangle, etc.

Comment: I think it was the Franklin company that popularised the broadened but specific use of the word 'classmate' referring to sets of words more loosely associated than synonyms.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - The Franklin company?

Comment: i invented 'one-hump', 'two-hump' for camels if this helps

Comment: @aparente001 [The Franklin company](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Franklin-Electronic-Wordmaster-Spellchecker-TMQ-200/dp/B00A6AVJ8G). Apparently, they use/d 'classmates' to mean 'words related by subject', so there might not be an exact match to 'words related by form and usage area'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about *sequence*?

Unicycle, bicycle, tricycle, ... are members of a *sequence*, as are onesome, twosome, threesome, ..., and triangle, quadrilateral, pentagon, ...

M-W:

> [*sequence*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sequence): a set of elements ordered so that they can be labeled
>   with the positive integers